# Copy SAP hana table into Azure SQL database and get SQL Server can't be found

Tags: sql-server, azure

I validated data factory and both source dataset and target dataset looks good and validated but as soon as I run pipeline and job hang on there and the error message as below.

> Operation on target Copy data1 failed:
>   ErrorCode=SqlFailedToConnect,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Cannot connect to SQL Server database: 'tcp:mysqlserver2002.database.windows.net,1433', Database: 'mySampleDatabase', User: 'system'. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Server database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.
>
> Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary
>   Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)
>
> Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
>   SqlErrorNumber=10060, Class=20, ErrorCode=-2146232060, State=0

Any idea and help will be appreciated

Thanks,

Comment: Please describe the mentioned pipeline you run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According you error message, the error happened in Source dataset, Data Factory don't have the permission to access the Source SQL database "mysqlserver2002.database.windows.net".

Please test the connection to the Source Azure SQL database like this:

[image]

If the connection failed, please check if you have opened the **Allow Azure services and resources to access this server** on Azrue SQL database firewall settings:

[image]

According my experience for this error, here are the solutions:

1. Set **Allow Azure services and resources to access this server** to
   **yes**
2. Add the client ip(which we could get from the error message) to the
   database firewall.

Another way, please [Add a role assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal) to Data Factory, then it will permission to access the database:
[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Leon, Thank you for help. I have validated both source dataset (sap hana) and target dataset (azure sql database)  and they are good. I also verified firewall setting and it is open to access. But as soon as I started pipeline and it hang on there and complained azure sql database can't be found. I am lost Thanks

Comment: @danielliu that's strange. I updated my answer and you can try the new way. If this still works, I also have no idea..

Comment: I tried all suggestion from you and it still didn't work. What I should do next?Just give up Azure?

Comment: Hi @danielliu, above the solutions is all we can find and get from the dcouments and per my experience. If all of this couldn't works. The last way is that call the Azure support On portal: [How to create an Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request), give them more error details ,they will contact you and help you solve it. Then check more things than us.

Comment: @danielliu That's all the things I can do for you. In the end, If my answer is helpful for you, can you please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)?This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.